# how to get id of one table in another table in jsp and servlet?

Tags: postgresql, jsp, join

I have a form with two text fields main category and sub category and both of them are inserted into two separate tables.

I want id of main category table to be inserted in sub category table as well right now it's showing null can someone please tell the way to achieve this or point me towards a document or other similar questions here (although i searched but didn't find anything according to my needs).

I'll add my codes and my tables for understanding the problem.

DAO:-

```
    public void insertCategory(MainCategory maincategory,SubCategory subcategory) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException 
    {
        Connection conn = DatabaseConnection.initializeDatabase();
        
        String query1 = "insert into list_of_main_categories (main_category) values (?)";   
        String query2 = "insert into list_of_sub_categories (sub_category) values (?)";
        
        try
        {           
            PreparedStatement prestmt1 = conn.prepareStatement(query1);     
            prestmt1.setString(1,maincategory.main_category);
            
            PreparedStatement prestmt2 = conn.prepareStatement(query2);         
            prestmt2.setString(1,subcategory.sub_category); 
             
            prestmt1.executeUpdate();        
            prestmt2.executeUpdate(); 
        }
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
```

Controller:-

```
    public void insertCategory(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws SQLException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, ServletException, ParseException
    {   
        String main_category = request.getParameter("main_category");  
        MainCategory newMainCategory = new MainCategory(main_category);
        
        String sub_category = request.getParameter("sub_category");  
        SubCategory newSubCategory = new SubCategory(sub_category);
        
        try 
        {
            productDAO.insertCategory(newMainCategory,newSubCategory);
        }   
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Categories.jsp"); 
        rd.forward(request,response);
    }
```

main category table:-

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBqSp.png     // this is working fine

sub category table:-

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/13Pfm.png    **// here i want the same m_id to be populated**

Answer (score 0):

You have not returned the m_id in you query1

try like this:

```
String query1 = "insert into list_of_main_categories (main_category) values (?) returning m_id ";   
String query2 = "insert into list_of_sub_categories (sub_category,m_id) values (?,?)";
        
        try
        {           
            PreparedStatement prestmt1 = conn.prepareStatement(query1);     
            prestmt1.setString(1,maincategory.main_category);

            ResultSet rs = prestmt1.executeQuery();
            
            int m_id = 0;
            
            while (rs.next())
            {    
                m_id = rs.getInt("m_id");     
            }

            PreparedStatement prestmt2 = conn.prepareStatement(query2);         
            prestmt2.setString(1,subcategory.sub_category); 
            prestmt2.setInt(2,m_id );
 
            prestmt2.executeUpdate(); 
        }
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```